# AWS Cloud Watch: Metric Filter Value Extraction from Log

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have api.log logs being sent to CloudWatch and I want to create a metric filter to extract the userId of the user tried to access application.

A sample log entry looks like:

```
2022-12-06T19:13:59.329Z    2a-b0bc-7a79c791f19c    INFO    Validated that user fakeId has access to the following gated roles: create, update and delete
```

And the value I would like to extract is: fakeId

I read through [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) and it seems pretty straight forward because user [fakeId] seconds is unique to just this line. This guide on metric filter syntax seems to only show examples for extracting values from JSON logs and this official example list doesn't cover it.

Based on the documentation and a few other stackoverflow answers, I tried these things:

```
[validation="Validated", that="that", user="user", userId, ...]
[,,user="user",userId,...]
[,,user=user,userId,...]
```

but it didn't. Any help would be really appreciated!